# How do I apply remove_if with a UUID comparison, using Boost lambdas?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I have a list of UUID's. I want to remove elements in the list with a given UUID. My question is, how do I achieve this, using boost lambdas and the `std::list::remove_if` method, so that I don't have to write a comparison function externally.

Comment: I'd take the [_Nair_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nair_(hair_removal)) approach and do it very carefully.

Comment: why not just `list.remove(the_uuid)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your container is a `std::list`, then you have the *member functions* `std::list::remove()` and `std::list::remove_if()`.

Since `boost::Uuid` already implements a comparison `operator==()`, then you can simply do:

```
std::list<boost::Uuid> uuids;
...
uuids.remove(uuidToRemove);
```

Answer (score 1):

Boost UUIDs are comparable and provide a comparison operator. You can just use std::remove when you know the UUID.

```
std::vector<boost::Uuid> uuids = /* ... */;
boost::Uuid toRemove;
uuids.erase( std::remove(uuids.begin(), uuids.end(), toRemove), uuids.end() );
```

If you want to, you could use boost bind to fix one argument

```
bool cmp(boost::Uuid const& x, boost::Uuid const& y) {return x == y;}
uuids.erase( std::remove_if(uuids.begin(), 
                            uuids.end(), 
                            boost::bind(cmp, toRemove, _2) )
              uuids.end() );
```

Comment: `std::remove` returns an iterator, you cannot assign it to a `vector`. Also, you have issues with a consistent use of the `boost` type. Plus, the OP is using `std::list`, which has `remove` and `remove_if`.

Comment: Yes, had an error in the assignment of the return type. Thanks. But what do you with "issues with a consistent use of boost type?

Comment: I meant `Uuid` vs. `uuid`, which you've fixed now. In order to really remove the element(s) from your `vector`, the call to `remove` should be completed by a `vector::erase`. Still, `std::list` does not need all of this.

Comment: Ok, this was just a typo. I overlooked that he really has a std::list type (I would almost always recommend to not use a std::list but a std::vector). I also added the call to std::erase, just in case somebody reads the answer later.